# Best way to display only URL domain using jinja2

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I have URLs stored in a Django model that I would like to display on a template, but I would only like to display the domain like this:

original_url:

```
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_process_simulators
```

display:

```
wikipedia.org/...
```

Would it be better to handle this on entirely on the back-end, font-end, or a custom function on with jinja2?

Answer (score 5):

If it is something you would later reuse in the templates throughout the project and, taking into account that there is a pretty simple logic involved, defining a [custom template filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters) would be perfectly okay here.

Use [`urlparse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to get the domain name:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> from jinja2 import Environment, Template
>>>
>>> def get_domain(url):
...     return "%s/..." % urlparse(url).netloc
... 
>>>
>>> env = Environment()
>>> env.filters['domain'] = get_domain
>>>
>>> template = env.from_string('{{ url|domain }}')
>>> template.render(url='https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_process_simulators')
u'wikipedia.org/...'
```

This is a simple example, you should additionally provide an error-handling mechanism in case `urlparse()` would fail parsing the url passed in.

Answer (score 5):

The best way would probably be a custom template filter as answered by @alecxe, but in case you can't, here is a non-fool-proof way for future reference.

```
{{ original_url.rpartition("//")[-1] }}
```

- `https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_process_simulators → wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_process_simulators`
- `//example.net/path/to/file → example.net/path/to/file`
- `ftp://example.net/pub → example.net/pub`

Get just the domain name (hostname):

```
{{ original_url.rpartition("//")[-1].partition("/")[0] }}
```

- `https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_process_simulators → wikipedia.org`
- `//example.net/path/to/file → example.net`
- `ftp://example.net/pub → example.net`

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Ansible. It is already built-in:

```
debug: msg="{{ 'https://google.com:443/' | urlsplit('hostname') }}"
```